# Incorrect boolean field output in Java

Tags: java, boolean, super

I'm doing a beginner Java tutorial and am trying to get the `lovesCatnip`and `isGuidedog` boolean fields to print out as `true` in my print output. My code runs and I currently get the below output.

```
Name: Animal Weight: 100 Sex: M
Name: Cat Weight: 50 Sex: F Loves Catnip: false
Name: Dog Weight: 60 Sex: M Is Guide Dog: false
```

Below is my code in achieving this output. There are two classes involved. The one below:

```
public class Animal {

    protected int weight; 
    protected String sex;
    protected boolean extra;

    public class Dog extends Animal{

        public Dog(int weight, String sex, boolean extra) {
            super(weight, sex, extra);
            this.extra = isGuideDog;
        }
        boolean isGuideDog;
    }

    public class Cat extends Animal{

            public Cat(int weight, String sex,boolean extra) {
            super(weight, sex, extra);
            this.extra = lovesCatnip;
        }
            boolean lovesCatnip;        
    }

    public Animal (int weight, String sex, boolean extra){
    this.weight =  weight;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.extra = extra;
    }
}
```

And this one

```
import apollo.exercises.ch07_inheritance.Animal.Cat;
import apollo.exercises.ch07_inheritance.Animal.Dog;

public class AnimalRunner {
    public static void main(String[] animals) {

        Animal animal = new Animal(100, "M", false);

        Cat cat = animal.new Cat (50, "F", true);

        Dog dog = animal.new Dog (60, "M", true);

        System.out.println("Name: Animal Weight: " + animal.weight + " Sex: " + animal.sex);
        System.out.println("Name: Cat Weight: " + cat.weight + " Sex: " + cat.sex + " Loves Catnip: " + cat.lovesCatnip);
        System.out.println("Name: Dog Weight: " + dog.weight + " Sex: " + dog.sex + " Is Guide Dog: " + dog.isGuideDog);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any advice on what I did wrong?

Comment: Just another reason why you use getters and setters. If you haven't learned about them yet, you soon will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Cat`class it is because of this line:

```
this.extra = lovesCatnip;
```

No mather what the value of `extra` is when you create the `Cat`, you are always assigning to it the value `lovesCatnip`, and as you never initialize it, it will be `false`.

Now, there is another problem and is with the use of your attributes, why do you have an attribute `extra` in your super-class if you will be creating `lovesCatnip` in the subclass and treating them as the same?

It sounds like you don't need the `extra` in the super-class at all.

Comment: Hmm... I take it that you want me to change `super(weight, sex, extra);` to `super(weight, sex);`? If I do that, my constructor is not properly defined, unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: Yes, and remove the `extra` attribute altogether from the parent class.

Comment: Something like the below? but if I do that, `super(weight, sex);` is still undefined.

`public class Dog extends Animal{
  boolean isGuideDog;
  public Dog(int weight, String sex, boolean b) {
   super(weight, sex);{
    
   this.isGuideDog = b;
  }
  
 } `

Comment: Yes, but did you also update the parent's constructor to expect 2 arguments ?

Comment: Oh yes I see! So I guess I learnt you can add fields in a sub-class instead of having to create the attribute in the parent class. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that the **default** value of a `boolean` in Java is `false`, and you are never assigning a value to `isGuideDog` or `lovesCatnip`:

```
boolean lovesCatnip; // default: false

boolean isGuideDog;  // default: false
```

I guess you would like to do something like this in your constructors:

```
boolean lovesCatnip;
public Cat(int weight, String sex,boolean extra) {
    super(weight, sex, extra);
    this.extra = extra;       // <-
    this.lovesCatnip = extra; // <- I'm not 100% sure if this is the desired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
this.extra = lovesCatnip;
```

should be

```
this.lovesCatnip = extra;
```

and

```
this.isGuideDog = extra;
```

You're modifying the passed in parameter (not assigning it to the field).